# What is the difference between env variables DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINERS and DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER?

Tags: c#, .net, docker, environment-variables

[**Edit 1**] [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73972395/how-to-use-environment-variables-dotnet-running-in-containers-and-dotnet-running?noredirect=1#comment130615383_73972395) is different from this one here (both mine), because here I ask about the DIFFERENCE (definition) between those variables, while in the other Q I asked what did I do wrong, when NONE of them seemed to work for me. That does not answer about their difference. I still ony have a vague suspect, the plural version is a consequence of older bug.

I have come accross these two variables but got confused about why do we need 2 and what is actually the difference between them.
[The official MS page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-environment-variables#dotnet_running_in_container-and-dotnet_running_in_containers) seems to be silent about this (as of now).
Anyone knows more ?

Comment: Seems like it was a mistake and now they have to support both for backwards-compatibility. See https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/677

Comment: If I run the latest aspnet image, only DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER is set

Comment: @MatthewWatson You are most likely right. It seems to be the consequence of a bug. Albeit it is not quite obvious to me from the git-gub bug report you shared...