# How to use environment variables DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINERS and DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER to determine where is .net application running?

Tags: c#, .net, docker, environment-variables

[The official MS page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-environment-variables#dotnet_running_in_container-and-dotnet_running_in_containers) suggests existence of "well known" environment variables, that are supposed to be set by 'official .NET images'.
Frankly, this seems to be true, but to my experience they are always set to 'false', even if I run app in a container.
I googled some example of usage and [this is what I found](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/detecting-that-a-net-core-app-is-running-in-a-docker-container-and-skippablefacts-in-xunit):

When I followed the same in a regular .net 5.0 app, I always get 'false' from this:

```
private bool InDocker { get { return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER") == "true";} }
```

Same result, if I try the plural version: DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER**S**
I have also tried to set the variable manualy in my Dockerfile like so:

```
ENV DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER = true
```

What could I be doing wrong ?

Comment: Looking at the dockerfiles in their github repo it should be set everywhere. But with the many frameworks and plattforms they provide it would be not unlikely that they forgot it for one. What base image you are using?  And by the way Net 5 is out of support.

Comment: @Ralf  `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0 AS base`
Yes - I know it is out of support - I upgraded all my projects the moment, when 6.0 went out. All was fine for intel platform. But building images for ARM (RPi) failed for a strange reason. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72308012/rpi-raspbian-docker-image-build-returned-a-non-zero-code-134-on-net-restore) So I had to 'retreat' back to 'safe' 5.0. Since RPi machines are out of stock for a long time,  its time to go forth once again - perhaps :-)

Comment: When i pull that image and do a `docker inspect mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0` i can see that env variable. So missing of that seems not the problem. Can you do a `docker inspect` on your running container and have a look at the env variables?

Comment: @Ralf  Yap - you are right. It is there:
`"Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80",

            "DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER== true",
            "DOTNET_VERSION=5.0.17"
        ],`

Comment: Öhm. Is there really a `==true`?

Comment: @Ralf Yes - cuz I've overwritten it - I realized..
See my answer below - that should make it clear. Many thanks for support.. U R welcome to compose your own answer with those points you have exposed in your comments for the convenience of future readers..

Comment: Its okay to me as it is. You might want to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was, that I also set my own ENV variable with the same name within my Dockerfile, which caused kind of overwritting the original variable.

In the image below, I have renamed my own ENV variable and set it to true like so:

> ENV DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER_PH = true

Perhaps I should have set it as string:

> ENV DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER_PH = "true"

[image: The result of setting own environment variable]

Many thanks to @Ralf for pointing out very good hints.
If you bother to compose an aswer in this manner, I will make it THE answer :o)